# Simple PHP/MySQL user registration works, but cannot login with the username

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a simple user login system to practice on my own machine.

I have a mysql table users with username, password, and email. I was able to register a new user with the following:

```
//short variable names:

$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];

session_start();

//attempt to register
register($username, $email, $password);
```

I created this function to input in db it works using the following function:

```
 function register($username, $email, $password){
//register new person with db
//return true or error

//connect to db
$db = db_connect();

//check if username is unique
$result = $db->query("SELECT * from user where username = '".$username."'");
if(!$result){
    throw new Exception('Could not execute query');
}

if($result->num_rows>0){
    throw new Exception('That username is taken - go back and choose another one.');
}

//if ok, put in db
$result = $db->query("INSERT into user values
        ('".$username."', sha1('".$password."'), '".$email."')");

if(!$result){
    throw new Exception('Could not register you in database - Please try again later.');
}

return true;
```

}

then I registered the variable

```
//register session variable
$_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;

echo 'Your registration was successful. Go to the members page to start setting up your profile!';
```

When I tried logging in with the username and password, it doesn't work here is the login code:

```
function login($username, $password){
//check username and password with db
$db = db_connect();

//check if username unique
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user where username = '".$username."' and password = sha1('".$password."')");
if(!$result){
    throw new Exception('Could not log you in.');
}
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    return true;
} else {
    throw new Exception('Could not log you in.');
}
}
```

I understand it's not secure it's just practice on my machine so I could move up, does anyone have any explanation? The password is registered as sha1 varchar in the db, and I think that's where I am not doing this right??

thanks for the help

Comment: Your code is _extremely_ vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: Do you get an error of any kind?

Comment: you should learn about sql injection / xss before putting this onto a public server.

Comment: How long is your varchar field for the password?

Comment: `I am working on a simple user login system to practice on my own machine.` Can't you people read?

Comment: What exactly does not work? I don't see you setting a session variable on successful login for example, could that be the problem?

Comment: Only hashing a password with SHA1 is not enough (there are plenty of rainbow tables out there). Use a salt and better, use bcrypt.

Comment: @SSHThis OP likely isn't the only person who'll ever see this answer. If I can raise awareness to problems in the code I will, not only might this help OP, it might also help future readers of this question. If you do not think my comment was helpful - that's ok, however keep in mind many people read SO, and every question that contains code susceptible to SQL injection might be another security hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely is in your **VARCHAR** definition for your password. **sha1** is 160 BIT long.

Anyways i would not suggest storing password in **VARCHAR** field instead use **BINARY(20)** and the **UNHEX** function to convert the **SHA1** value to binary.

with a lot of records in database (thousands, millions) binary(20) takes much less memory than varchar or char.

**OR** change it to **CHAR(40)**

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
function login($username, $password){
//check username and password with db
$db = db_connect();

//check if username unique
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user where username = '".$username."' and password = sha1('".$password."')");
if(!$result){
    throw new Exception('Could not log you in.');
}
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    return true;
} else {
    throw new Exception('Could not log you in.');
}
}
```

I changed your condition checking num rows.